# Patrol procedure (Loop moving from point A to point B)

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to get a turtle "patrol" from point A to point B.
Here's what I have tried:

```
-> to go procedure:
    to patrol
      set heading 90
      ifelse ( pxcor < 14 and pxcor > 6 ) 
      [ fd 0.1 ]
      [ bk 4 ]  
    end
```

It works but the when reaches the else statement the turtle gets "teleported", i know the method above is not really the solution.

*I need the turtle to go back to point A with 0.1 speed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want at point A or point B to just rotate and keep walking. This is how I would do that.

```
to patrol ;; assuming the initial position is within 6 to 14.

  if pxcor = 14 or pxcor = 6 
  [ rt 180]
  fd .1 
end
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Comment: no big deal, but I'd probably shorten `set heading heading + 180` to just `rt 180`, it does the same thing